# Displaying a loader in a table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some problems with displaying an AJAX loader inside a table cell.

I want it to be displayed over the cell to underline that there is data being loaded into it. However, I am experiencing problems with properly positioning it.

My base solution:

CSS:

```
.loader {
    z-index: 30;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f00; /* Red, so I could see it properly */
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
displayCellLoader: function (cell) {
  var loader = $("<div>").addClass("loader").css({
    width: cell.width(),
    height: cell.height(),
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  });
  cell.append(loader);
}
```

However, this design has some flaws:

1. If the table cells have padding (and they have) the loader won't cover it
2. The loader will be displayed below any content the cell contains, not over it (as exppected)

A screenshot of the problem:
[image: Loaders without padding]

I thought the best way to eliminate these flaws would be to position the loader absolutely but it caused a different problem:

The loader's `left` and `right` CSS properties are taken from the results of the `offset()` method, however for an unknown reason the loaders are displayed somewhat moved to the right (and a little to big).

Here is my modified JS:

```
displayCellLoader: function (cell) {
    var offset = cell.offset();
    var loader = $("<div>").addClass("loader").css({
        width: cell.innerWidth(),
        height: cell.innerHeight(),
        left: offset.left,
        top: offset.top
    });
    body.append(loader); /* body is $("body") */
}
```

And this is how it looks like now:
[image: Loaders moved to the right]

Does anyone know why does it happen?

And, more importantly, is there a better way to do it?

EDIT: There was a solution posted, about a way I didn't mention here - appending absolutely positioned div into a td, which has `position: relative`. At first I thought "How on Earth could I forget about such obvious method?", however after testing it, I noticed that it doesn't work. The divs became positioned relatively to the table container, not to the cell itself.

I googled the issue and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638/using-position-relative-absolute-within-a-td). Quoting the best answer,

> This is because according to CSS 2.1, the effect of position: relative
>   on table elements is undefined.

So this solution doesn't apply to my case. The way to go would be to modify the template so all my table cells contain a div with `position:relative` which I could use to position the loaders. This solution is kind of painful for me, because it involves a lot of modifications in my code, so I'll use it as a last resort.

I also don't know why did the poster delete his answer - it could prove useful to others.

Comment: Well, I have "found" a way to solve it with wrapping the contents of the td with a relative div and then absolutely positioning the loader inside it. If noone finds a better way, I'll post and accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up embedding cell contents into a div, like this:

```
displayCellLoader: function (cell) {
    var paddingTop = parseInt(cell.css("padding-top"));
    var paddingLeft = parseInt(cell.css("padding-left"));
    var tempDiv = $("<div>").css({
        position: "relative",
        height: cell.height()
    }).html(cell.html());
    cell.empty().append(tempDiv);
    var loader = $("<div>").addClass("loader").css({
        width: cell.width(),
        height: cell.outerHeight(),
        top: -paddingTop,
        left: -paddingLeft
    }).append($("<img>").attr("src", "images/loader-cell.gif"));
    tempDiv.append(loader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in a slightly different way - with absolute positioning, outerWidht/height & offset:

http://jsfiddle.net/tdSDY/

Comment: Thak you for your answer but it does not work properly in my case, probably because of some style and html differences.