# Why absolute position is not right under Firefox 16.0.2

Tags: css, firefox, position, css-position

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EW6Ax/13/)

After I upgraded to FF 16.0.2, the absolute position has problem.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Html Part

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            Product 1
            <span>Button</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            Product 2
            <span>Button</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

​

CSS Part

```
tr { height:250px; }
td {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px; bottom:10px; left:10px; right:10px; /* as padding */
}
span {
    position:absolute; bottom:0; left:50px;
    width:90px; height:20px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background:#ccc;
}​
```

What I want to display is this way:

[image]

Comment: What's the actual question/problem here? What does "not right" mean?

Comment: Please see the screeshot I just added.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome 23, but not Firefox 16.0.1

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6079254

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is: in the [CSS 2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position), `position: relative` doesn't work on table elements.

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

One solution is to add another `<div>` inside the `<td>` and make that `position: relative` instead.

<sub>Note: Answer shamelessly "stolen" from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6079254</sub>