# images dont show up correctly in browsers

Tags: html, image, background

I have an image on this [website](http://thomaswd.com/maze) . It shows up on every browser, but its positioned wrong in Firefox. I also have another image, on the same website, in the maze, when you open it in safari, its a gray box. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have screenshots of these bugs?

Comment: Are you talking about the 'Finish' image? Make your question more clear.

Comment: yes, I am talking about the finish image and the mouse image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `position: relative` is undefined in the Firefox rendering engine. Therefore your absolutely positioned image jumps to the next parent element which has positioning (the `section` element).

[See more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6079254/911140)

If you just remove the absolute positioning on the image, it looks like it is in the correct spot anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by removing the below property from image

```
position:absolute;
```

If 'absolute' is necessary, Try adding this in your CSS

```
.finish {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
```

Hope it will help you to align 'finish' image

Comment: thanks, this worked..but my gray box is still showing up in safari

Comment: @user2034878: i cant see any grey box in my safari(v5.1), Do you have any screenshot?