# Relative Positioning not working on a Table Row.

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have installed and am using IE10 and Chrome.
AND I'd like to fixed the top header `<tr>` in `<table>`.
but below style tag dose not working!!

```
<tr style="position:relative;top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);"></tr>
```

Do anybody have like this experience? 
If these were bug, I also want another solution to solve this problem.
PLZ help me!

Comment: write your code here. then only we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Aadietya They did, it wasn't formatted for SO.

Comment: The answer to this question is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638/using-position-relative-absolute-within-a-td

Comment: @user2376490 read stackoverflow FAQ for how to ask question

Answer (score 0):

Relative positioning inside of `<table>` tags is not supported. [Table rows](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html) in fact are simply containers for the bits that show in the GUI (the `<td>` and `<th>`). You can style the [background color of the table row](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp), but very few other visual aspects extend to this element. Because tables already contain positioning by design it's a waste of time trying to overwrite it. You should either use `<div>` tags and style them with positioning or use the built-in [Table CSS styles](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp).

Additionally check out the answer here:
[Using Position Relative/Absolute within a TD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638/using-position-relative-absolute-within-a-td#answer-6079254)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to check out the contents about the GUI(<td> and <th>). because I saw the relative positioning applied to td. Could you tell me where is I can check out that?

Answer (score -2):

create some http://fiddle.jshell.net/

so we can understand your code.