# Div position issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html, position

I am working on this code and this code working fine in `Chrome` but not in `Firefox`

Here is code

```
<html lang="en-US">
<body><table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="position: relative; width: 50%; height: 500px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="position: absolute; background-color: blue; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div></td>
<td style="position: relative; width: 50%; height: 500px;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

[If you want to see here is JSFiddle for code in working](http://jsfiddle.net/8KYFw/)

Please explain me why `div` in `Firefox` covering whole width of the screen, it should cover only 50% width as `Chrome` is showing.

Comment: Is this a real-world use case, or is this a puzzle? These are some very odd things to want to do.

Comment: Do you really need `position: absolute;`?

Comment: interesting... it only happens in table too...

Answer (score 3):

Possibly because as of the [2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning) relative positioning on table-cell elements is undefined by CSS:

> The box's position is calculated according to the normal flow (this is called the position in normal flow). Then the box is offset relative to its normal position. When a box B is relatively positioned, the position of the following box is calculated as though B were not offset. **The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.**

This is not true as of the [Positioned Layout Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position/) (They explicitly define the behaviour) but it hasn't been adopted by vendors yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `position: absolute;` of the inner DIV:

```
<html lang="en-US">
  <body>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="position: relative; width: 50%; height: 500px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="background-color: blue; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
          </td>
          <td style="position: relative; width: 50%; height: 500px;">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can test this with an [update I made to your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KYFw/2/).

If you really need to use an absolute positioned div inside a cell, then you should put inside that cell a relative positioned div that contains the absolute one:

```
<td>
  <div style="position: relative; ... ">
    <div style="position: absolute;... ">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

[This another update to the original jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KYFw/4/) shows an absolute div inside the relative one, with an offset of 30 from the left and 10 from the top.

This old thread here in stackoverflow may be useful: [Using Position Relative/Absolute within a TD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638/using-position-relative-absolute-within-a-td)

Comment: Corrected the second jsfiddle uri.