# Position a button relatively to the top of its parent node

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is supposed to contain images. When howering an image, I want a control buttons to appear at the top of the table cell.

```
<table id="pridat_fotky">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="empty">
                <button>X</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, what I tried wa giving the table cell a `position:relative` and `position:absolute` for the button:

```
table#pridat_fotky td {
  position: relative;
}
/**THE BUTTON**/
table td button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;   /*0 means as hight as possible within the cell???*/
  left: 50%;  /**MIDDLE ALIGMENT???*/
}
```

Unfortunatelly, with this setup, the button aligns itself to the top of the window.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BhTq/2/), Button is a little red square.

#### [Working solution here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2BhTq/6/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6079254/2188587

Comment: your fiddle work's great for me. try clearing your browsers cash and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a block level element around the content of you table cells, something like the following:

```
<td class="empty">
    <div><button>X</button></div>
</td>
```

and add the following rule to your CSS:

```
table#pridat_fotky td div {
    /**TO MAKE THE BUTTON APPEAR RELATIVE?**/
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

`position: relative` is not valid on table cells, but it is valid on a block level element within a table cell.

You also need to set `height: 100%` to make the div fill up the table cell, and then the placement works nicely.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/k9fWN/

**Note:** You need to add the wrapper `div` to all the table cells where you want to place the button.

Comment: I saw your working demo and the positioning works very nicely.  Looks good!

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your CSS.
In line 17, you are missing ":", (left 50%;)