# How to fill DIV element into td parent?

Tags: css

I have actually a little problem with filling TD tag. I will see 100% height of td setup on div inserted to TD

http://pastebin.com/Z4apksVw

How to fill any div to 100% of parent height ??

**SOLVED**

```
<?php 
`http://jsfiddle.net/s5rbv/`
?>
```

Working under firefox 26, other browser i don't check because i dont needed

Comment: can you make your question clear?

Comment: I need to have a div with 100% height of TD rowspan="2".

Comment: If your reason for stretching is to have a background color on the cell, just put the style on the `<td>` instead.

Comment: No, It have to be DIV

Comment: I am with xec on this, please explain what are you trying to do beside stretch your div! Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: It have to be DIV because TD representive a time of work and DIV (with draggable from UI Jquery) representive meet with patient.

Comment: Can you look at this and see if it helps you!
http://www.reignwaterdesigns.com/ad/tidbits/hacks/minimum_height_in_css.shtml

Answer (score 0):

For your question: "How to fill any div to 100% of parent height ??" Just set the child's div height to 100% and it will fill the height of the parent element.

```
childDIv{
    height:100%;
}
```

**Edit** With your new info you provided, here is a solution for your problem maybe:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4dDL/4/

HTML

```
<table>
<tr><td rowspan="2"><div>row 1 and 2</div></td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>col1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;  
    background-color:red;
}

td div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:200px;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:green;    
}
```

You set the div to position absolute and left and top to 0 to set it top left of the td element, but need to set the td to relative for it to work. Then set the height of div to 2x the height of the td element. But for it to appear over top of the second row (rowspan=2), you need to set a z-index.

**EDIT**

Actually, if you fill the full cell, dont need to use positioning, and it doesnt work on firefox anyways. as pointed out in comments.

here is a working fiddle with update: http://jsfiddle.net/s4dDL/13/

Comment: This won't make the `div` stretch to the `td` unfortunately. http://jsfiddle.net/N8MG7/

Comment: The entire problem comes from the rowspan, which your demo is lacking.

Comment: This is still no good, `position: relative;` will not work on a `<td>`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638

Comment: It'd be easy with javascript... can you use javascript?

Comment: im pretty sure its can work with only css i should not use JS

Comment: See the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/s4dDL/4/  it works, you just have to manually set the height... unfortunately 100% sets it for the row only not the rowspan=2. otherwise why not just use the td element rather than a div

Comment: Firefox doesn't support position: relative on td/th. See this in FF http://jsfiddle.net/s4dDL/10/

Comment: Regarding your fiddle update #8, you can't just set all the divs to 200px (double a single td height), just the one's that are double rows. See this fix: http://jsfiddle.net/s4dDL/11/

Comment: Actually yea, you dont need the positioning and it doesnt work on firefox, if you fill the cell completely it  doenst need to be positioned. See this fix, removed positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/s4dDL/13/