# Why have a span element in a th header?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to tidy up some HTML produced by a long gone developer and  wish to know if there is any earthly reason to have a span element covering the whole of a th header. Is there some formatting trick I'm missing?

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th><span>Heading with words</span></th>
       <!-- more th elements -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <!-- table rows here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If there is a styling application, e.g. heading centering that could be the reason, and which cannot be done without the `span` please provide an example.

Comment: Inspect the element and check if it is inheriting any styles from the CSS or something. Could be styling aspect only, I can think of. There could be nothing.

Comment: I can think of several reasons why it might be useful to do that. I wouldn't want to speculate on which (if any) apply in your case, there isn't a whole lot of context.

Comment: Alas, you shouldn't ask us, but the author of that code ;)

Comment: check CSS and look for any rule that is assigned to `th > span` or `th span`. otherwise the developer was too much container fan!!!

Comment: Could be some css for targeting, like `#myTable th > span`, but other than that? No reason that I can think of.

Comment: I'd ask the author but they're not with the company any more.

Comment: I can't think of any targetting that can't be applied to the th element itself, or solved through better class use.

Comment: Who knows, maybe the `long gone developer` did this just to make you scratch your head and come to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Try deleting the `span` and see what changes, you will probably find your answer pretty quickly. There are many reasons you might have this markup, one of which would be applying styling to :pseudo elements that you want relative to the inline text rather than it's container.

Answer (score 1):

There are a certain number of things related to `display` and `position`-ing you cannot do on a `td` or a `th`, and generally on `<table>` elements. The only solution is to wrap its contents in a `<span>` or `<div>` and work on that wrapper.

Of course, the recommended way to go is **not to use** HTML `<table>`s for anything other than displaying tabular data (in which case you'll probably not need any `position`-ing or `display` properties set on its `<td>`s or `<th>`s, but that's a completely different story).

Comment: As it stands, your answer is interesting but needs an example.

Comment: How about [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6079254/1891677)?

Comment: Agreed with @AndreiGheorghiu! `:)`

Comment: We may have a winner. I'll accept it if there's no alternatives by tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: It will be closed by tomorrow. Way too broad and inviting to speculation.  Wait, it already is. That was fast. :))