# How to make a link (anchor) tags 100% height of containing th/td tags?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with the following basic structure:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a href="">Header Text</a>
      </th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Random text</td>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Where the `a` link tags can be clicked to re-sort the table.

I want to define some CSS so that regardless of how many lines the text within the `a` tags span across, all of the `a` link tags will take up 100% the height of their containing `th` tags so that you can click anywhere within the table header to sort on a particular column.

I tried using the following CSS, but it only worked in Chrome:

```
th {
  height: 1px;
}
th a {
  height: 100%;
}
```

I also know that you could use JavaScript to solve this problem, but I'd really like to avoid that if possible. In other words, an HTML/CSS only solution would be ideal.

I have to support IE back to IE8 and pretty much all versions of Chrome, FF, etc. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Old version relied on duplicating the link and hiding a copy while sizing the other outside of document flow, but we can do better... here's better.

You can get it to work in relatively modern Chrome (39.0+) and Firefox (31.2+) and in the last version of Safari for Windows (5.1.7) via `::before`.

In IE, it won't quite size it right on its own (same problem as with the doubling), but by tossing in an `overflow:hidden`, making the `height` larger than 100%, and adding `::after` with clever positioning, you can mitigate this problem fairly easily.

If you set the heights back to 100% you can force the banding IE has to be visible.

Obviously, the background-shading on hover is purely for demonstrative purposes.

In addition, I figured out how to make elder fox (FF 3.5.2, welcome to CSS3) degrade cleanly. That's what `.safety` is for, and it was actually easier to do than I had expected.

```css
    body{
        background: #f06;
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    .safety{
        position:relative;
    }
    th{
        position:relative;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    
    a{
        display:block;
    }
    a:hover{
        text-decoration:none;
        background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    }
    a::before{
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        height:900%;
        width:100%;
    }
    a::after{
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        height:900%;
        width:100%;
    }
    a:hover::before{
        background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
    }
    a:hover::after{
        background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
    }
```

```html
<span class="safety">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="">The Link</a></th>
            <th><br /><br />next cell<br /><br /></th>
            <th><a href="">The Link 2<br />Naturally Taller</a></th>
            <th>next cell</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>streeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeetch</th>
            <th>next cell</th>
            <th>next cell</th>
            <th>next cell</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

---

### Why pseudoelements?

Because we didn't remove the link itself from document flow, the link is still able to greedily grab the screen real-estate it itself needs.

And since we can position and size them separately, we can mitigate any bugs with how the browser picks what `100%;` means without removing the link.

---

### Why you can't simply say `height:100%;`

Firstly, `a` is an `inline` element, meaning it is only as big as its content. Ergo, sizing on it itself fails without making it a `block` or `inline-block`.

However, that only makes `width:100%;` work in this case.

If you want to have a `height:100%;` you *must* declare what 100% is in a *non-internally-relative* manor that can be propagated down to the percentage-based element. That means no percentages (outside of the screen units `vh, vw, vmin, vmax`), as otherwise you'd get "correct" behavior when something scales its size upwards, creates more scroll bar, then scales its size upwards more in an infinite loop.

You CAN bypass this, however, via `position:absolute`, since that removes the element from the normal flow- as in it is not allowed to increase the size of its parent, so it cannot produce an infinite loop.

Since the parent has a knowable finite size if it doesn't scale to its relative-height child, `height:100%;` on the `absolute` element will be used (in the expected manner) *so long as the `absolute` element is also a `block` or `inline-block` element* (as `inline` is force-sized by its contents).

It also will require a `width`, even if `block`, because it has been removed from document flow and thus no longer knows for certain how wide it should be (parent or anchoring ancestor?)

---

### Aside

The change of implementation was thanks to Lea Verou's book, and I felt like a total dunce when I read her suggestion of using `::before`- especially since I've actually used it for expanding the clickable area before.

Also, what the hell is an element to its pseudo-elements? Parent from an affair with the CSS?

Comment: Is it a problem if you replace table with divs and use flexboxes

Comment: Still haven't learned flexboxen (it's on my todo list), so I'm talking out my ass, but if flexboxen can grow their parents after the initial render, __yes__. The issue is because a `height:``x``%` child could force its parent to grow/shrink, and thus, grow/shrink itself again, thus grow/shrink its parent, thus grow/shrink itself again, thus grow/shrink its parent, thus grow/shrink itself again... you get the idea. Not even `height:100%;` is safe, as what if the element with that isn't the only child, and the other child grows the parent because of its sibling taking up too much space?

Comment: The only reason `width` gets away with is is width is tied to `100vw` as its cap, since the web's english-origin core said U/D for default scrolling rather than L/R scroll. Because of that, the browser can make a reasonable assumption as to how wide something is ever allowed to be, and go from there. You can probably run into the loop ban with `width` but you'd have to intentionally trigger it.

Comment: @ClaudioKing Character limit made tagging hard. Heh. Sorry.

Comment: abluejelly, I love the idea of this, but I tested it quite a bit in the latest Chrome, FF and IE11, and it only works right in Chrome. FF gets close, but it has some weird 1px spacing around the top and left edges. Basically, if you assign a very contrastive background color to the `th`, it becomes very obvious. And in IE11 (with auto updates) it doesn't work at all. It's as if you just had `display: block` `a` link tags in `th` elements with nothing else. I also tried switching out `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` for `bottom: 0` and `right: 0`, but no such luck.

Comment: In other words, I might be doing something wrong, but I don't think so, so if this does in fact work, could you please create a demo that demonstrates it because I'm not seeing it in FF and IE11? Thanks.

Comment: This SO link may be useful in explaining why the `position` `absolute`/`relative` thing doesn't work in all browsers with `td`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638/using-position-relative-absolute-within-a-td

Comment: @HartleySan Odd that it doesn't work in FF since I pretty much test in only FF by default.... but I'll fiddle with it, gimme a bit. Btw, `pos:rel` on `th, td` should still work for the child-attaches-to-parent, just not reposition- what version are you using? I've literally been using that in production code with an GTE IE 9 requirement and have had no problems...

Comment: @HartleySan [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/17677e4846766a82641a) I see what you mean in IE, doesn't work at all, but I don't see anything off in Firefox 31.2 (what I have installed). It does fail in Firefox 3.5.2, though, so it would be that `pos:rel` issue. Wrapping it in a div at least solves the link covering the entire page, but then the trick for getting full size fails. IE seems completely unsalvageable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105740/discussion-between-abluejelly-and-hartleysan).

Comment: @HartleySan Made a major update to the solution, figured you might wanna get ping'd since I reworked practically the entire thing. Still doesn't have legacy support way into the past, but it degrades gracefully now, and I solved the GTE IE 9 problem. Jankily, but a fix is a fix. Didn't test IE 8, just need to switch the `::` pseudo-element designations to `:` pseudo-class designations.

Answer (score -1):

As long as there's no cell padding on the TH, this should work:

```
th {
  height: 2em;
}
th a {
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: The height of the th elements is variable, so setting a static height is not an acceptable answer. Sorry.