# position: absolute inside table cell not working as expected in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table cell, which contains an arrow on the bottom right of the cell:

[Correct table cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7iBR.png)

This works fine with all browsers except Internet Explorer, where the arrow aligns somewhere in the middle:

[Incorrect table cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIIjl.png)

The html of the table cell looks something like this:

```
<td>
  <a>Pitstop</a>
  <a class="arrow"></a>
</td>
```

And the CSS something like this:

```
td {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Position Relative/Absolute within a TD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638/using-position-relative-absolute-within-a-td)

Comment: what version of exploder? works for me in 11 https://jsfiddle.net/35w1czk5/1

Comment: If height is set a specified value, it is ok; but if you use `top: 0; bottom: 0;` to auto expand the height as the td, it does not work