# How we make first three columns with headings of a html table to be fixed and other all columns could be scroll-able

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question makes me feel like it's a duplicate, but after going through multiple related threads I have realised... I have gone through most related threads ([fixed columns](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/g8pfBXOcY9)) regarding my requirement, and after following the answers I'm faced with some text overlapping issues like below...

[image: text_overlapping_issue]

I am trying to achieve something like *make the first three columns with headings of a* `html` *table to be fixed, and all other columns could be scroll-able*.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td,
        th {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 5px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        th {
            background: #444;
            color: white;
        }

        td.width100px div,
        th.width100px div {
            width: 100px;
        }

        td.width86px div,
        th.width86px div {
            width: 86px;
        }

        td.width120px div,
        th.width120px div {
            width: 120px;
        }

        td.width150px div,
        th.width150px div {
            width: 150px;
        }

        td div {
            word-break: break-all !important;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #eee;
        }

        #main_container {
            padding: 10px;
            overflow: auto;
            margin: 5px;
            border: solid 2px darkgrey;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main_container">
        <div style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px;z-index:1;width: 150px;position:sticky;left:0;top:0;margin-bottom: 5px;font-weight: 600;">2020-12-29</div>
        <div style="width:100%">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="width100px">
                        <div>EmpName</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width86px">
                        <div>EmpIdD</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width100px">
                        <div>MTN</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width120px">
                        <div>WorkingTime</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width86px">
                        <div>StartTime</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width150px">
                        <div>Location</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width86px">
                        <div>LunchTime</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width150px">
                        <div>Location</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width86px">
                        <div>EndTime</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width150px">
                        <div>Location</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="width100px">
                        <div>William Reehil</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>12345</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width100px">
                        <div>91657897698</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width120px">
                        <div>09:00-17:00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>10:30</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>13th Street. 47 W 13th St, New York, NY 10011, USA</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>13:00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>16:50</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="width100px">
                        <div>William Reehil</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>12345</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width100px">
                        <div>91657897698</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width120px">
                        <div>09:00-17:00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>10:30</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYarkNNewYark NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>13:00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>16:50</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px;z-index:1;width: 150px;position:sticky;left:0;top:0;margin-bottom: 5px;font-weight: 600;">2020-12-29</div>
        <div style="width:100%">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="width100px">
                        <div>EmpName</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width86px">
                        <div>EmpIdD</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width100px">
                        <div>MTN</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width120px">
                        <div>WorkingTime</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width86px">
                        <div>StartTime</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width150px">
                        <div>Location</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width86px">
                        <div>LunchTime</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width150px">
                        <div>Location</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width86px">
                        <div>EndTime</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="width150px">
                        <div>Location</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="width100px">
                        <div>William Reehil</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>12345</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width100px">
                        <div>91657897698</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width120px">
                        <div>09:00-17:00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>10:30</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div> NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>13:00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>16:50</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="width100px">
                        <div>William Reehil</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>12345</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width100px">
                        <div>91657897698</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width120px">
                        <div>09:00-17:00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>10:30</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div> NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>13:00</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width86px">
                        <div>16:50</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width150px">
                        <div>NewYark</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: date wise employees report table]

So, finally - I want achieve something like this:

[image: first_three_columns_with_headings_should_be_fixed]

What things can I try?

Comment: One simple solution I was thought about is split it to 2 separated tables, the first table is 3 first columns - no scroll, the second one is the rest columns and scrollable.

Comment: I too thought same @thanhdx but when have more text in second table that time rows are looks miss mapping :(

Comment: @Venki try the two table solution and then explain the problems in it.

Comment: @DumbCoder7 Sure, let me try it.

Comment: @DumbCoder7, please have a look here https://pasteboard.co/J1X8WJx.png as having a less text in first table and having more text in second table and its getting wrap down so in this case text pushing a row to down a bit. So first table first row and second table first row are not in sync :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt a standard `HTML Table` to conform to your needs.

With tables the mechanics are laid out nicely in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6079254/11455272) answer by **avernet**, so please read that as to the issues you would face regarding directly manipulating the table.

You can make use of wrappers and `nth-child` `class selectors` a collection of these can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/).

Now for a demo of how this wrapping works is below...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .Light{
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
        .Dark{
            background-color: darkgrey;
        }
        table{
            border: none;
            padding:none;
            margin:none;
            min-width: 1200px;
        }
        table tr th{
            padding-left: 15pt;
            height:24pt;
        }
        table tr td, table tr th{
            padding: 15pt;
            min-width: 150px;
        }
        
        .tableWrap{
            max-width: 800px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }
        .ParentPos{
            position: absolute;
        }
        .ChildPos{
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            right:0;
            top:-0.575rem;
            bottom:0px;
            height: 100%
        }
        /*First 3 cells in the header row:*/
        table tr th:nth-child(-n+3){
            position: absolute;
            padding-top: 27pt;
            padding-bottom: 4pt;
        }
        /*First 3 cells in the content row:*/
        table tr td:nth-child(-n+3){
            position: absolute;
            padding-top: 27pt;
            padding-bottom: 16.75pt;
        }
        table tr th:nth-child(2), table tr td:nth-child(2){
            left:145pt;
        }
        table tr th:nth-child(3), table tr td:nth-child(3){
            left:287pt;
        }
        table tr th:nth-child(4){
            padding-left: 440pt;
        }
        table tr td:nth-child(4){
            padding-left: 500pt;
        }
        /*Making the spacing even out:*/
        table tr th:nth-child(n+5){
            padding-left: 0pt;
        }
        /*Making the spacing even out:*/
        table tr td:nth-child(n+5){
            padding-left: 60pt;
        }
        /*This sets alternating colours on each odd numbered column:*/
        table tr:nth-child(odd) td, table tr:nth-child(odd) th {
            background-color: lightgrey;  
        }
        /*This sets alternating colours on each even numbered column:*/
        table tr:nth-child(even) td, table tr:nth-child(even) th {
            background-color: darkgrey;  
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tableWrap">
       <table cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Heading 1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <th>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Heading 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Heading 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>Heading 4</th>
            <th>Heading 5</th>
            <th>Heading 6</th>
            <th>Heading 7</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Content 1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Content 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Content 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
            <td>Content 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Content 1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Content 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ParentPos">
                    <div class="ChildPos">
                        Content 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
            <td>Content 7</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bridge Keeper for your time. I am tried with your suggestion its working when all table content having similar background color but when we trying with different background color on even & odd content rows in that case text is overlapping as I shown in my ask ?

Comment: @Venki I've updated the answer to have alternating colours on odd and even columns

Comment: A big thanks @Bridge Keeper & sorry for late reply. Its really useful for me now. Thanks again.

Comment: actually I need alternative colors in horizontal rather in vertical way and I made code changes like below 

    **table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: darkgrey;
        }**  then seeing text overlapping issue. Can you please help on this ?

Comment: Hi @Venki I see horizontal row colours is what you needed let's fix it. This is because the changes you made to show different coloured rows are applied to the `tr` and not the `td`, you want to style each individual `td` of the row so you were close you just needed to specify the `td` after the alternating `tr` I've updated the answer.

Comment: You are super @Bridge Keeper, and now I got how I want exactly. Thank you again for your big help and fabulous skills.

Comment: Oh! Yeah you are right @Bridge Keeper, I did not now.

Comment: sorry for troubling you again :( this time its regarding when any **<td>** have more content then doing horizontal scroll then header 4 content is overloading with header 3 content [please see here](https://ibb.co/99cLG8Z) and I debugged somewhat and comes to know like you have been using padding-bottom somewhat but when **<td>** having more content by that time that specific padding-bottom is not enough to hide complete header 4 content while scrolling horizontally. Can you please help on this Bridge Keeper?

Comment: have been raised one more request for that bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115383/html-table-td-content-overloading-with-another-static-td-content-while-horiz) if you have time can you please look there?