# HTML table <td> content overloading with another static <td> content while horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

as per my project need I made first three columns content and headings of a table be static by using **position** and **left** css properties and made remaining columns be scrollable horizontally like below [image]

But when having more content in non static columns then that non static column content is displaying over static column content like below [image]

and notice one more thing if any non static column having more content then other non static columns content moving down(may be because of first three columns be having **position:absolute** but not sure) from starting point like below but they should be aligned from top only as per my need
[image]

*source code:*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width:900px;
        }

     
          /*This sets alternating colours on each odd numbered column:*/
          table tr:nth-child(odd) td
        {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        /*This sets alternating colours on each even numbered column:*/
        table tr:nth-child(even) td
        {
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        /*  tr:nth-child(add) {
            background-color: #eee;
        } */
        tr th,
        td {
            padding: 5px;
            width:100pt;
            height: auto;
        }

        tr th{
            text-align: left;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        div{
            width:700px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="position:absolute;left:0pt;">Heading1</th>
                <th style="position:absolute;left:80pt;">Heading2</th>
                <th style="position:absolute;left:140pt;">Heading3</th>
                <th>Heading4</th>
                <th>Heading5</th>
                <th>Heading6</th>
                <th>Heading7</th>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:0pt;">Content1 Content1 Content1 Content1</td>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:80pt;">Content2</td>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:140pt;">Content3</td>
                <td>Content4</td>
                <td>Content5 Content5 Content5 Content5 Content5</td>
                <td>Content6</td>
                <td>Content7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:0pt;">Content1</td>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:80pt;">Content2</td>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:140pt;">Content3</td>
                <td>Content4</td>
                <td>Content5</td>
                <td>Content6</td>
                <td>Content7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:0pt;">Content1</td>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:80pt;">Content2</td>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:140pt;">Content3</td>
                <td>Content4</td>
                <td>Content5</td>
                <td>Content6</td>
                <td>Content7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:0pt;">Content1</td>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:80pt;">Content2</td>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:140pt;">Content3</td>
                <td>Content4</td>
                <td>Content5</td>
                <td>Content6</td>
                <td>Content7</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What things can I try? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

About vertical position, this is the solution :

```
td {vertical-align:top;}
```

Is it possible to force the height of the cells ?
If so, height:50px solves the first problem.

Comment: Thank you @AlainPre that **td {vertical-align:top;}** looks fine for vertically top position and second one we can't predict always comes some fixed number of characters or lines of content will come from service :(, is there any possibility to apply height is auto (**height:auto**)? and I tried your second solution also but when more content is there then again seeing same issue :(

Comment: May be **min-height:50px;**
this property set a minimum height but let this height grows if necessary.

Comment: have been tried with min-height but no luck :(. thank you for yours suggestion.