# How can I have a textarea take up the remaining height in a div?

Tags: html, css, image, styles, textarea

I have a set of code as per below. The point is to have a set of images be in the div, and the remainder of the div is populated with a textarea.  If I set the height = 100%, it will make it the same height, which isn't the (div.height - images.height) and makes the textarea longer.

It says on w3c that `inherit` doesn't work at the moment, `auto` will just make a default textarea, and hardcoding it will never accomplish it as the div could be bigger or smaller.

What have you all done to accomplish this?

```
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "images" style="background-color:#99ccff;">
    <img style = "padding:0px; border:0px;" src = "..." />
    <img style = "padding:0px; border:0px;" src = "..." />
    <img style = "padding:0px; border:0px;" src = "..." />
    <img style = "padding:0px; border:0px;" src = "..." />
    <img style = "padding:0px; border:0px;" src = "..." />
    <img style = "padding:0px; border:0px;" src = "..." />
    <img style = "padding:0px; border:0px;" src = "..." />
  </div>
  <textarea style="width:100%; height:100%; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;" >
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the height of `#parent` defined? Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that shows the problem? (you can use http://dummyimage.com/ for the images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be impossible to get this behavior work in other browsers than chrome.

I've tried to split the pictures and textarea in two CSS table-rows to give `#images` a height so that `#textarea-container` automatically adjust its height. The next step was to give textarea 100% height and 100% width.

*Absolute positioning an element in a relative positioned table cell is not supported*:
 [CSS Positioning inside of an HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280115/css-positioning-inside-of-an-html-table)

So `textarea { position: absolute; left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:0 }` in a relative positioned table cell will not work.

**HTML**

```
<div id ="parent">
    <div id="images">
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/100x20/cc5acc/fff.png" />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/80x20/cc5acc/fff.png" />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/20x20/cc5acc/fff.png" />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/80x20/cc5acc/fff.png" />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/100x20/cc5acc/fff.png" />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/120x20/cc5acc/fff.png" />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/50x20/cc5acc/fff.png" />
    </div>

    <div id="textarea-container">
        <textarea></textarea>    
    </div>    
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin:0; padding: 0 }

#parent{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    display: table;
    background: blue;
}
#images {
    display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}

#textarea-container {
    display: table-row;
}

textarea {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**!** This solution depends on `display: table`, `display: table-row` and Google Chrome.

**Live demo (works only in google chrome)**: http://jsfiddle.net/atTK7/4/
**Display table support**: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

A Javascript workaround for browsers, except for chrome, is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a problem with your browser. I just tried your code and seems to do what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/Rorok_89/DMdyY/1/

Comment: I believe the OP wants the textarea on the same line as the images.

Comment: not on the same line.  I want it to fill the remaining content.... so like all the images would wrap and take up some total height, then as my comment above:  I would have some sort of fill command which would take the remaining heigh and apply it to the textarea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at using it, but you may wish to try display:box;. I have an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyomu/atTK7/2/embedded/result/) that does what (i think) you want, but with the 'main bug' being that you can no longer re-size the textarea (but if that's not and issue, you can change resize:none;).

Comment: Also, more on [Flex-Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Answer (score -1):

Even if I don't know clearly what you want to do, you can use jQuery to help you to get the size of actual elements, and force your textarea to expand or reduce. This should help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var max_div_height = 1000; //The max height of your div in pixels
var total_div_height = 0 // The total height of your divs combined
jQuery(".container").each(function(){
    var context = $(this);
    var height = context.height();
    total_div_height+=height; //If it's width, set height otherwise
});
var textarea_size = max_div_height - total_div_height;
jQuery("#myTextarea").css("height", textarea_size+"px") // Give an ID to your textarea
</script>
```

Comment: The OP hasn't tagged with question with jQuery nor JavaScript.

Comment: I do not want to use JS for this.  I was hoping it was just something to do entirely with CSS.... like some sort of fill command... to fill the remaining height of the container with the textarea.